# Why is the createRequire function not found?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Per the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename) I have the following code...

```
//test.mjs
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const DoSomething2 = module.createRequire("../dist/sce.cjs");
```

but when I run with `node --experimental-modules test.mjs` I get..

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'module' does not provide an export named 'createRequire'

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? createRequire is a new feature. BTW, module.createRequire should be createRequire

Comment: version 12 I can try upgrading to 13

Comment: Still getting the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said above, `module.createRequire` should be `createRequire`

```js
//test.mjs
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const DoSomething2 = createRequire("../dist/sce.cjs");
```

*module* refers to the current file (think *module.exports*)
*Module* refers to `require('module')`
Only the latter contains *createRequire*

Also, `createRequire` cannot take relative paths. Use `path.resolve`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
import { createRequire } from 'module'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)
const data = require('./sce.cjs')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does in attempt to find a solution to the question.